# Sketching a region of a joint density function

Tags: probability, graphing-functions, density-function

This problem is from the textbook by John Rice, "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis":

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density function

$f(x,y)=k(x-y),$ for $0\le y\le x\le 1$ and $0$ elsewhere

Sketch the region over which the density is positive.

How would you do this question? How do you account for $k$? I should note that $k$ is some constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region where $f(x,y)$ is positive is a triangle in the $(x,y)$ plane bounded by the lines $y=x$, and the $x$ axis, both between $x=0$ and $x=1$, and the line $x=1$ between $y=0$ and $y=1$.

To calculate $k$ use the fact that $k\int_0^1\int_0^x (x-y)dydx=1$.

Comment: What was the intuition behind knowing that its a triangle? I wasn't sure how to do it because of the unknown constant and the question in my textbook has us sketch the shape before finding $k$.

Comment: $k$ has no effect on the shape.   The basic idea to get this shape is first notice that all points are on the unit square. Then since $y\le x$, the line $y=x$ is a boundary.